# DateFormatter ValueError when trying to format date label

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am not very familiar with pandas and plotting but I've tinkered with it in the past. I'm trying to plot two lines in the same figure to compare data from last year and this year. I want to tweak the ticks to my liking, starting with the date format, trying to make it as condensed as possible so I'm going after the format `%d-%m`. This is how I'm doing it:

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxxxx.csv', index_col='date')
df19 = df['2019-01-01':'2019-04-30']
df20 = df['2020-01-01':'2020-04-30']
df19r = df19.rolling(7).mean().dropna()
df20r = df20.rolling(7).mean().dropna()

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df19r.plot(ax=ax)
df20r.plot(ax=ax)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%d-%m')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(fmt)
plt.legend(['2019', '2020'], loc='best')
plt.show()
```

However, the labels won't get rendered due to an error:

```
ValueError: DateFormatter found a value of x=0, which is an illegal date.  This usually occurs because you have not informed the axis that it is plotting dates, e.g., with ax.xaxis_date()
```

I'm not sure where to go from this, because my indices are well formatted dates:

```
['2019-01-07' '2019-01-08' '2019-01-09' '2019-01-10' '2019-01-11'
 '2019-01-12' '2019-01-13' '2019-01-14' '2019-01-15' '2019-01-16'
 '2019-01-17' '2019-01-18' '2019-01-19' '2019-01-20' '2019-01-21'
 '2019-01-22' '2019-01-23' '2019-01-24' '2019-01-25' '2019-01-26'
 '2019-01-27' '2019-01-28' '2019-01-29' '2019-01-30' '2019-01-31'
 '2019-02-01' '2019-02-02' '2019-02-03' '2019-02-04' '2019-02-05'
 '2019-02-06' '2019-02-07' '2019-02-08' '2019-02-09' '2019-02-10'
 '2019-02-11' '2019-02-12' '2019-02-13' '2019-02-14' '2019-02-15'
 '2019-02-16' '2019-02-17' '2019-02-18' '2019-02-19' '2019-02-20'
 '2019-02-21' '2019-02-22' '2019-02-23' '2019-02-24' '2019-02-25'
 '2019-02-26' '2019-02-27' '2019-02-28' '2019-03-01' '2019-03-02'
 '2019-03-03' '2019-03-04' '2019-03-05' '2019-03-06' '2019-03-07'
 '2019-03-08' '2019-03-09' '2019-03-10' '2019-03-11' '2019-03-12'
 '2019-03-13' '2019-03-14' '2019-03-15' '2019-03-16' '2019-03-17'
 '2019-03-18' '2019-03-19' '2019-03-20' '2019-03-21' '2019-03-22'
 '2019-03-23' '2019-03-24' '2019-03-25' '2019-03-26' '2019-03-27'
 '2019-03-28' '2019-03-29' '2019-03-30' '2019-03-31' '2019-04-01'
 '2019-04-02' '2019-04-03' '2019-04-04' '2019-04-05' '2019-04-06'
 '2019-04-07' '2019-04-08' '2019-04-09' '2019-04-10' '2019-04-11'
 '2019-04-12' '2019-04-13' '2019-04-14' '2019-04-15' '2019-04-16'
 '2019-04-17' '2019-04-18' '2019-04-19' '2019-04-20' '2019-04-21'
 '2019-04-22' '2019-04-23' '2019-04-24' '2019-04-25' '2019-04-26'
 '2019-04-27' '2019-04-28' '2019-04-29' '2019-04-30']
```

Bonus question: I managed to change the labels in the legend with `plt.legend(['2019', '2020'], loc='best')` but what if the order changes? How can I plot a DataFrame while renaming its column?

Comment: Looks like the index is strings instead of dates. You can find out via `df.info()`.

Comment: I thought pandas/matplot lib had a smart feature to autodetect date-like strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have loaded the dataframe with:

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxxxx.csv', index_col='date')
```

It works fine but the `date` column contains `str` values instead of `pd.Timestamp` ones.

You should use:

```
df = pd.read_csv('xxxxx.csv', index_col='date', parse_dates = ['date'])
```